# Store modifier value not being output inside Matrix

Tags: expresso-store, matrix

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Matrix or Store.

With the following code:

```
{modifiers}
{if modifier_name=="Linen"}
{modifier_options}
<input type="radio" name="{modifier_input_name}" id="{modifier_input_name}-{option_id}" value="{option_id}">
<label for="{modifier_input_name}-{option_id}" class="swatch-label">
  {product_fabric_swatches search:product_type="=Linen" search:product_swatch_name="={option_name}"}
  <img src="{exp:ce_img:single src='{product_swatch}'">
  {/product_fabric_swatches}
</label>
{/modifier_options}
{/if}
{modifiers}
```

I get this output:

```
<label for="modifiers_13-61"> "}
    <img src="…/1-0003-0001_60_60.jpg" data-src="…/1-0003-0001_800_533.jpg">
```

You can see it outputs the label and associated image but it's not filtering on the `{option_name}` and there's a stray `"}` after the label which appears to be the closing of the Matrix tag.

If I replace `{option_name}` with one of the values entered into Matrix, then I get the output I expect, but obviously only for a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this with an embedded template.